# TBB C++ multithreading error: No matching function for call

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

The following C++ code is for Intel TBB. This code was generated by the Flow Graph as well. 
I have 2 compilation errors:

```
No matching function for call to 'make_edge'
No matching function for call to 'make_edge'
```

Here is code with definitions:

```
 function_node< tbb::flow::tuple<char *,char *>, char * > result_reporter(position3_g0, 1, []( const tbb::flow::tuple<char *,char *> & in ) -> char * {...

function_node< char *, char * > sott_target_node(position3_g0, unlimited, []( char *buffer ) -> char * {
```

Here is the TBB calling code that creates the compilation errors

```
make_edge( result_join, result_reporter);

make_edge( sott_target_node, input_port< 2 >( result_join ));
```

I would glady provide all the code but StackOverflow prevent too much code with little description. Can any one help out figure out these errrors? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the input of the function_node incorrectly.  A function_node with an input of `tuple<char *, char *>` takes a predecessor with a `tuple<char *, char *>` output.

If this is what you want (that there be two inputs to the node each of `char *` type, and an output of `char *`) you should use a combination of an [`indexer_node`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/530503) (which has multiple input ports, and any input on any port will cause a message to be emitted with the port number and the input wrapped) that connects to a `function_node` that takes the output type of the `indexer_node`.  Please see the documentation, and ask if you have any questions.

Comment: If you need the node to only be fired when it receives an output from all of its predecessors, You need a join_node.  https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506236 .  There are three policies for joining; I'd guess you want a queueing join.  The indexer_node immediately forwards each message it receives from each port; the join waits until it has at least one input at each input port before it forwards them.  The output of the join is a tuple.